# HTML Calendar and JS problems

Tags: javascript, php, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I would like to make a Javascript-based calendar for managing holidays.
My problem is, I am using a SQL database to store the holidays, which I am accessing with PHP. How can I use the results of the PHP query in a JS Script ?

For example, to add holidays for an employee i have to do that :

```
<?php $req='select Nom,DateDebut,DateFin,NbJour from conge where Statut="Valide"';
$res=mysqli_prepare($connect,$req);
$var=mysqli_stmt_execute($res);
$var=mysqli_stmt_bind_result($res,$Nom,$DateDebut,$DateFin,$NbJour);
while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($res)) {
   // ???
}
?>
<!-- partial -->
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.7/semantic.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js'></script>
      
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.1.0/fullcalendar.min.js'></script><script>
          
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
        },
        defaultDate: '<?php echo date("Y-m-d");?>',
        navLinks: true, 
        editable: true,
        eventLimit: true, 
        events: [
            {
                title: '<?php echo $_SESSION["Login"]?>',
                start: '2021-04-30',
                end: '2021-05-03'
            }
```

When I am just using a `<?php echo $_SESSION ?>` it is working perfectly. But when I try with the loop around `stmt_fetch($res)` it's not working. How could I do that?

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/events-json-feed - let fullCalendar do the heavy lifting for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since best practices dictate that you should separate your PHP and presentational code as much as possible, what you want to do is build an array of data within PHP, and then safely dump it into your JavaScript when it's needed. Always use `json_encode()` when inserting data into JavaScript from PHP to ensure proper escaping of values.

I'd also recommend against using mysqli; but if you must, at least use the object-oriented interface. It's much easier to use and results in a slightly more modern-looking code.

```php
<?php
$query = 'SELECT Nom, DateDebut, DateFin, NbJour FROM conge WHERE Statut="Valide"';
$stmt = $connect->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($Nom, $DateDebut, $DateFin, $NbJour);
$events = [];
while($stmt->fetch()) {
    $events[] = [
        "title" => "Vacances de $Nom",
        "start" => $DateDebut,
        "end" => $DateFin
    ];
}
?>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev, next, today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month, basicWeek, basicDay'
        },
        defaultDate: '<?= json_encode(date("Y-m-d"), \JSON_HEX_TAG) ?>',
        navLinks: true, 
        editable: true,
        eventLimit: true, 
        events: <?= json_encode($events, \JSON_HEX_TAG) ?>
    });
})();
```

Comment: Even better would be to separate the code which generates the events into a different endpoint which just returns the events in JSON format, and only returns events which are relevant to the date range the calendar is currently displaying (thus creating a dynamic, efficient event feed), as described at https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/events-json-feed

Comment: Agreed, though I think Ajax is a bit beyond the scope of this answer!

Comment: Perhaps, but the beauty of it is OP doesn't need to actually write any Ajax code - the calendar handles it, OP just needs to write the PHP script and supply the URL

Comment: Thanks @miken32, that's why I love Stack Overflow. Pls continue to help beginners like me. Ur awesome <3